# How to optimize a SQL query that combines INNER JOINs, DISTINCT and WHERE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

```
SELECT DISTINCT options.id, options.foo_option_id, options.description
FROM vehicles 
INNER JOIN vehicle_options     ON vehicle_options.vehicle_id = vehicles.id 
INNER JOIN options             ON options.id = vehicle_options.option_id 
INNER JOIN discounted_vehicles ON vehicles.id = discounted_vehicles.vehicle_id 
WHERE discounted_vehicles.discount_id = 4;
```

The query above returns me 2067 rows, and it runs locally in 1.7 seconds.
I'm wondering if it is as fast as it can be or if I can tweak it further somehow, as this dataset will grow fast overtime.

Things that I've tried without change in speed:

1 - Change the join order, joining from the smallest to the biggest table.

2 - Adding an index to discounted_vehicles.discount_id.

Comment: Check the [explain plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/using-explain.html), and see if you can add any indexes, or whether any query changes will help

Comment: You can't optimize a query without having an estimate of the sizes of the data sets, and once you have an estimate, the best way to check the performance is to fill up tables to that size and see what happens. It depends on your hardware and heavily on *what* the data is. If most rows only join to one row in the other table, that's a hugely different case than if most rows join to 200 other rows. The bottom line is that the best advice anyone can give you is to profile it and stop guessing. You can also set concrete performance goals (expected time of completion) and see if you're meeting them

Comment: Please provide information as described in the [tag info of \[postgresql-performance\]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best query depends on missing information.
This should be substantially faster in a typical setup:

```
SELECT id, foo_option_id, description
FROM   options o
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT
   FROM   discounted_vehicles d
   JOIN   vehicle_options vo USING (vehicle_id)
   WHERE  d.discount_id = 4
   AND    vo.option_id = o.id
   );
```

Assuming referential integrity, enforced by FK constraints, we can omit the table `vehicle` from the query and join from `discounted_vehicles` to `vehicle_options` directly.

Also, `EXISTS` is typically faster if there are many qualifying rows per distinct option.

Ideally, you'd have multicolumn indexes on:

```
discounted_vehicles(discount_id, vehicle_id)
vehicle_options(vehicle_id, option_id)
```

Index columns in this order. You probably have a PK constraint on `vehicle_options` providing the 2nd index, but the column order should match. Related:

- [PostgreSQL composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352056/postgresql-composite-primary-key/11352543#11352543)
- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Depending on actual data distribution, there may be faster query styles. Related:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Changing the **join order** is typically **futile**. Postgres reorders joins any way it expects to be fastest. (Exceptions apply.) Related:

- [Sample Query to show Cardinality estimation error in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002263/sample-query-to-show-cardinality-estimation-error-in-postgresql/25002962#25002962)
  [SQL INNER JOIN over multiple tables equal to WHERE syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418581/sql-inner-join-over-multiple-tables-equal-to-where-syntax/27420244#27420244)
- [Why does a slight change in the search term slow down the query so much?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343860/why-does-a-slight-change-in-the-search-term-slow-down-the-query-so-much/36347677#36347677)

Answer (score 0):

> 1 - Change the join order, joining from the smallest to the biggest table.

Behind the scenes PostgreSQL rearranges the order of the tables according to the explain plan the SQL optimizer designs. The order you wrote is not meaningful.

> 2 - Adding an index to discounted_vehicles.discount_id.

It depends on how selective the `discount_id` column is. Do you think it will filter out 95% of the rows leaving only 5%? If it leaves 5% or less, an index will help. Otherwise a full table scan is faster.

Additionally, if it's not there yet, I would add the index:

```
vehicle_options (vehicle_id)
```

But maybe it's already created by the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Try using groupby instead of distinct

```
SELECT 
    "options"."id",
    "options"."foo_option_id",
    "options"."description"
FROM
    "vehicles" 
    INNER JOIN "vehicle_options" ON "vehicle_options"."vehicle_id" = "vehicles"."id" 
    INNER JOIN "options" ON "options"."id" = "vehicle_options"."option_id" 
    INNER JOIN "discounted_vehicles" ON "vehicles"."id" = "discounted_vehicles"."vehicle_id" 
WHERE 
    "discounted_vehicles"."discount_id" = 4 
GROUP BY 
    "options.id";
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, you need to create necessary indexes before that try to run below query

```
SELECT "options"."id", "options"."foo_option_id",
    "options"."description"
  FROM "vehicles" 
  INNER JOIN "vehicle_options" 
    ON "vehicle_options"."vehicle_id" = "vehicles"."id" 
  INNER JOIN "options" 
    ON "options"."id" = "vehicle_options"."option_id" 
  INNER JOIN "discounted_vehicles" 
    ON "vehicles"."id" = "discounted_vehicles"."vehicle_id" 
  WHERE "discounted_vehicles"."discount_id" = 4
  GROUP BY options"."id", "options"."foo_option_id",
    "options"."description"
```